# Weird launcher bar/chrome bug, hard to describe

Tags: unity, launcher, google-chrome

I have Chrome locked to the launcher, but when I click it, it opens another icon on the launcher. When I hover over it, it says the name of one of my bookmarks. I've unlocked and locked to no avail. [Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZyt0.jpg). The first Chrome icon on launcher just says Google Chrome when hovered over. In the screenshot, it still says the bookmark, so it's not changing according to what page I have open (which is ask ubuntu in the screen) I want to make the Chrome icon launch normally again. Thanks for any help.

Comment: This was such a tough question to ask, when it happened to me I didn't know how I was going to describe it. Well asked, FourZer0 and -prajmus well answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just solved this problem with my Chrome.

Go to `~/.local/share/applications/` there will probably be a file named `google-chrome-stable.desktop`. If there's not try `grep -i 'one world from your bookmark name'` and it should return the file containing this false launcher.

Inside this file should be a line with something like `Name=Your bookmark`. If so, you are safe to delete it (just in case check if you have `/usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop` on your system, otherwise you won't get any icon)

Comment: Same problem but I made it worse, I deleted the wrong ones... so now I'm stuck without a desktop file. I can launch from launcher, but not from the launcher shortcut bar...

Answer (score -1):

I can't see a screenshot, but I'm on mobile right now so that may not be your fault.

Close and unlock Chrome from the launcher, reboot, then open Chrome and lock it to the launcher again. That may fix your issue.

Comment: Still happening. I also noticed that when searching for Chrome in dash search, both the regular chrome and the one titled a name of a bookmark show up. I'm gonna reinstall chrome, didn't think of that before, hopefully that works.